# Content of Fragment not loading every time when using the NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Navigation Drawer with 6 Fragments. One of them should contain a ListView. I got it to work and I can switch through all the Fragments via the Navigation Drawer. When I press on the one containing the ListView I can see it, just as it should be. However, when I go to the same Fragment (containing the ListView) while I'm in it already, the ListView isn't displayed anymore. This is probably due to the fact, that I set the ListView on the `onActivityCreated()` method in the Fragment. I'm curious now though, what happens when I press on the same Fragment again. Does the activity stay loaded and the Fragment needs to be inflated again and through this the `OnActivityCreated()` method isn't called again? And if so, what do I have to do, that the ListView gets displayed again?

My `Fragment.class` currently looks like this:

```
public class FahrplanFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private Resources res;
private String[] plans;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

public FahrplanFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fahrplan, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview_fahrplan);
    res = getResources();
    plans = res.getStringArray(R.array.plans);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, plans);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))

> Called when the fragment's activity has been created and this
>   fragment's view hierarchy instantiated. It can be used to do final
>   initialization once these pieces are in place, such as retrieving
>   views or restoring state. [..] This is called after
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) and before
>   onViewStateRestored(Bundle).

It is called every time. You can check by logging the event.

Can you post the code of the event handling when click on the navagition drawer button?

***EDIT 1***

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/giacomodeglinnocenti/fragment-lifecycle/src/226f463814b1144331a9a5f0d273a6a8158b19aa/app/src/main/?at=master) I re-created you project to test it and it works. The fragment loads every time with the list view inside. Moreover, it displays the events when they happens and shows clearly that `onActivityCreated` is called every time the fragment is replaced.

The best suggestion I can give here is to log your code using `Log.d()` or `System.out.println("...")` in various steps of the code, or even better enter in debug mode by setting breakpoints and inspect the code while it's running to understand when it enter in some methods and when not.

Comment: Oh, I'm using `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new FahrplanFragment());` at the moment. So I replace the whole fragment but I don't initiate the ListView anymore since `onActivityCreated()` is only called after I create the Activity. So how do I have to change it, that it rebuilds the ListView after I replace the fragment with itself?

Comment: onActivityCreated() is called EVERY TIME. I logged it for you... check [this](https://bitbucket.org/giacomodeglinnocenti/fragment-lifecycle/src/3cb251418a682020ce792726d3027fe99da0e9a5/app/?at=master) . I think the problem is in your list view initialization.

Comment: I looked at your code and used Toasts and logs as well to see what gets called and in which order. I also saw that the `onActivityCreated()` method gets called every time when I click on the corresponding Navigation Drawer item. The fragment_layout gets inflated and the `onActivityCreated()` method get called in the right order every time, but when I'm already in the Fragment the ListView doesn't show... It must be overwritten by something else then right? I'll test it further but maybe you have an idea for me :)

Comment: I have updated the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/giacomodeglinnocenti/fragment-lifecycle/src/226f463814b1144331a9a5f0d273a6a8158b19aa/app/src/main/?at=master) with exactly what you trying to do, and it still work, the list is recreated each time. Do you confirm that your code works the first time?